# JavaScript compare object prototype and sum them

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, javascript-objects

I'm stuck with a JavaScript exercise, I need to create a script in JavaScript that the user insert the month and the ML of rain belong to that month and the program will returns a table with the month and the rain, but it needs to sum the rain of the repeat month, example January repeat three times so the table needs to show the sum of those three months.

I did this, but keep looping twice the repeat month and I don't know how break it after the sum of the repeat month, here is the code:

```js
var proceed = true;

function Mes(mes, lluvia) {
  this.month = mes;
  this.rain = lluvia;
}

datos = [];

meses = ["Enero", "Febrero"];

while (proceed) {
  var mes = prompt("Ingresa el mes", "");
  var lluvia = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese los ml de lluvia correspondiente al mes", ""));

  new Mes(mes, lluvia);
  datos.push(new Mes(mes, lluvia));
  proceed = confirm("Deseas continuar?");
}


for (var j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
  if (datos[j].month == meses[0]) {
    var initialValue = 0;
    var sum = datos.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator + currentValue.rain;
    }, initialValue)
    //document.write("El acumulado de todos los meses ingresados es de " + sum);

    document.write("<table>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>" + datos[j].month + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + sum + "</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");
    document.write("</table>");
  } else {
    document.write("<table>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>" + datos[j].month + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + datos[j].rain + "</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");
    document.write("</table>");
  }
}
```

Comment: This line `new Mes(mes, lluvia);` is unnecessary. It creates an object but doesn't save it anywhere.

Comment: Hello @Barmar thanks for your reply, sorry I don't understand the answer of the duplicate question you mentioned, could you please help me with my doubt? I'm trying to sum the values of the prototype that are repeat, I tried like this if ( datos[j].month ==  meses[0] ) {} but it keeps repeating the result twice, I think I need a break; but I don't know where to put it. I'm on the right track? Thanks

Comment: Why are you only comparing with `meses[0]`?

Comment: You should create an object whose keys are the month names and values are the totals for that month. Loop over your array of objects, and add the rain to the total for that month. After you've done that, you can create your table from that object.

Comment: @Barmar I only comparing to meses[0] because I was only testing Enero, sorry I didn't mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object whose keys are the month names and values are the rain totals. Loop over your array and add each rain amount to the appropriate total.

Also, you should only create one table; the loop should create just the rows.

```js
var proceed = true;

function Mes(mes, lluvia) {
  this.month = mes;
  this.rain = lluvia;
}

datos = [];

meses = ["Enero", "Febrero"];

while (proceed) {
  var mes = prompt("Ingresa el mes", "");
  if (meses.includes(mes)) {
    var lluvia = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese los ml de lluvia correspondiente al mes", ""));
    datos.push(new Mes(mes, lluvia));
  } else {
    alert("Mal mes");
  }
  proceed = confirm("Deseas continuar?");
}

var totals = datos.reduce((obj, {month, rain}) => {
  if (month in obj) {
    obj[month] += rain;
  } else {
    obj[month] = rain;
  }
  return obj;
}, {});

document.write("<table>");
document.write("<tr><th>Mes</th><th>Total</th></tr>");

meses.forEach(month => {
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>" + month + "</td>");
  document.write("<td>" + totals[month] + "</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
});
document.write("</table>");
```